# How to import jregex library to ballerina app

Tags: libraries, ballerina

I’m trying to validate regex in Ballerina using library samjs/jregex from https://central.ballerina.io/samjs/jregex
I’m trying to get this executed:

```
import ballerina/io;
import samjs/jregex;

public function main() {
    //io:println(Commons:isValidDateTime("dupa"));
    jregex:Pattern p = jregex:compile(regex = ".r");
    jregex:Matcher m = p.matcher(input = "br");
    var b = m.matches();
    io:println(b);
}
```

I have run command `ballerina pull samjs/jregex`

My `Ballerina.toml` is:

```
[project]
org-name= "organization"
version= "0.1.0"

[platform]
target= "java8"

[[platform.libraries]]
artifactId = "mssql-jdbc"
version = "8.2.0"
path = "./mssql-jdbc-8.2.0.jre8.jar"

[dependencies]
```

However this is not working, because I’m getting error:

```sh
error: module not found: ballerinax/java:*_java8 or ballerinax/java:*_anyerror: samjs/jregex:0.2.0::/src/jregex/matcher.bal:1:1: cannot resolve module 'ballerinax/java'
error: module not found: ballerinax/java:*_java8 or ballerinax/java:*_any
error: samjs/jregex:0.2.0::/src/jregex/pattern.bal:1:1: cannot resolve module 'ballerinax/java'
error: samjs/jregex:0.2.0::/src/jregex/matcher.bal:85:29: undefined module 'java'
error: samjs/jregex:0.2.0::/src/jregex/matcher.bal:85:29: undefined function 'fromString'
error: samjs/jregex:0.2.0::/src/jregex/matcher.bal:128:69: undefined module 'java'
error: samjs/jregex:0.2.0::/src/jregex/matcher.bal:128:69: undefined annotation 'Method'
```

it seems that import of jregex requires ballerinax, however I cannot import to code anything that is not directly used (Ballerina does not allow for "empty" imports).

Does anybody knows how to import this regex library to make it working in application?

Comment: I've updated the jregex module and pushed a new version to the central. Please check now. I was using an old version of a module internally.

Comment: Thnak you very much! All problems are gone now!

Comment: Now it works perfect.